# Add subject and address directly from user input

Tags: java, pdf, invoice, letter

I'm trying to let user add data and it will be directly displayed inside a pdf, i honestly don't know how, I've been trying for about ten days and I still can't figure it out, I want for example to let user enter address, name and object into different parts of pdf, like a letter, this is something i found on YouTube but he only showed how to fill up tables:
[image]

I want to be able to add the address and name on the side etc., not permanently , i want it to change whenever a new user adds their address and name, another field here to let the user add address and they should not be inside the table, I'm working with android studio and java, if anyone knows how i can achieve this ill be very very thankful.
[image]

Comment: Well, we can't very well help you without your code. What have you tried? Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably try this using web app